# i2c connection to mopi not working on one image

Tags: i2c

I'm trying to setup a mopi on my model B running raspbian. At the moment I can't talk to the mopi unit using the mopi and mopicli utilities and i2cdetect shows the following...

```
$ i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 0b -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

After a fair amount of head scratching I installed a fresh copy of raspbian on a spare SD card and tried that (with no other changes to the hardware). That worked as it should and the two "UU" entries in the i2cdetect output have gone away.

Whilst I've got a way forward (copying stuff from original install to the fresh install) I'm worried that I don't understand why this is happening (and so I'm not confident that it won't happen again). What should I be looking at? I've disabled the start of the application installed in the original image (which doesn't use i2c but does use some of the gpio pins) but that hasn't helped.

Comment: Just found http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15906/i2c-device-doesnt-work-on-different-arch-linux-install after searching for [i2c] UU (which I should have thought of before). I'll check software/firmware/kernel versions this evening.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I gave up an did a fresh install - just couldn't spot any difference between working and non-working versions.

Comment: If the fresh install was from a newer image and you have not ran both `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade` *and* applied `rpi-update` (which you would need to install) on the old one, you may have ended up with a kernel/firmware mismatch or suffered from a bug that was subsequently fixed.